# Two Key Up events and I need data from both into two variables outside these events

Tags: javascript

- I have two Key Up events, which log values of two different `input` elements.
- I want to combine both values from both events into one variable.
- I have the following snippet.

```js
var textInputSVK = document.getElementById("top__itextsvk");
var textInputKg = document.getElementById("top__itextkg");

function delay(e, delay) {
  let timer = 0;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(e.bind(this, ...args), delay || 0);
  };
}

textInputKg.addEventListener(
  "keyup",
  delay(e => {
 var t = textInputKg.value;
    console.log(t);
  }, 500)
);

textInputSVK.addEventListener(
  "keyup",
  delay(e => {
 var t = textInputSVK.value;
    console.log(t);
  }, 500)
);
```

```html
<input id="top__itextkg" type="text" value="10" autocomplete="off" />
<input id="top__itextsvk" value="10" autocomplete="off" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case to use streams. We can use RxJS to solve this kind of problems very easily.
Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-7w4ruz)

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using `Event Bubbling` in which we will enclose the two input elements into a div and then identify the child element in which Key Up event is pressed.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");

function delay(e, delay) {
  let timer = 0;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(e.bind(this, ...args), delay || 0);
  };
}

parent.addEventListener(
  "keyup",
  delay(e => {
   var t = e.target.value;
    console.log(`this event is from ${e.target.id}`,t);
  }, 500)
);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <input id="top__itextkg" type="text" value="10" autocomplete="off" />
  <input id="top__itextsvk" value="10" autocomplete="off" type="text" />
</div>
```